# Exporting multiple parts with CSS exportparts

Tags: css, web-component

I have a web component that is nested inside of other web components and I am working on a [theming](https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/) solution for my components. I need a way to export multiple parts but what I am trying to do does not work and styles are not applied when I try to export multiple parts.

Here is the structure:

```
<my-component>
  <other-component exportparts="theme-btn theme-dropdown"/>
</my-component>
```

Then in my CSS:

```
my-component::part(theme-btn) {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

No style is applied. However, when I only export one part like this: `exportparts="theme-btn"` in the `other-component` it works and applies the styles. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-exportparts) on this is severely lacking.

You're very close. Instead of using a space to separate the different parts in `exportparts` you should use a comma `,`.

Your new code would be:

```
<my-component>
  <other-component exportparts="theme-btn, theme-dropdown"/>
</my-component>
```

And now you can style both the `theme-btn` and the `theme-dropdown` parts.

Comment: Although [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/exportparts) is still pretty sparse, it does link to [the relevant section of the spec](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-shadow-parts/#element-attrdef-html-global-exportparts) which includes details of the syntax.